Zonal harmonics and irreducible representations
Some easy preliminary definitions:
(1) $SO(n+1)$ acts on $C^\infty(S^n)$ by $A^*f(x):=f(Ax)$ for all $f\in C^\infty(S^n)$ and $x\in S^n$,
(2) $f\in C^\infty(S^n)$ is called zonal iff $f$ is invariant under $SO(n)$, that is $(1\oplus A)^*f=f$ for all $A\in SO(n)$. If $V\subseteq C^\infty(S^n)$ is a subspace, denote by $Z(V)\subseteq V$ the subspace (sic!) of zonal functions.
Prove the following: If $V\subset C^\infty(S^n)$ is a subspace with $1\leq \mathrm{dim}V<\infty$ and such that it is invariant under $SO(n+1)$, then $\mathrm{dim}Z(V)\geq1$. I am totally stuck but the hint is the following: Fix $x_0\in S^n$ and consider $\phi\colon V\to\mathbb C$, $f\mapsto f(x_0)$.
My ideas: I think it should be possible to argue that without loss of generality, I can assume $x_0=e_1$, the first basis vector in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. Moreover, choose a basis for $V$, consider its dual basis, then decompose $\phi$ into this dual basis. But I do not know how to proceed. As far as I can see, I need to prove the existence of a non-trivial $f\in V$ that is also an element of $Z(V)$.
Any help is welcome.
Edit: The next steps I would like to take are showing that

If $\mathrm{dim}Z(V)=1$ then $V$ is irreducible.
The space of all harmonic homogeneous polynomials $\mathbb H_m(\mathbb R^{n+1})$ of degree $m\geq0$ on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$
is an irreducible representation of $SO(n+1)$.


For nonzero $f\in V$, pick $x\in S^n$ for which $f(x)\ne 0$. WLOG (via rotation), $x=e_{n+1}$. Apply Weyl's unitary trick: average all rotations of $f$ around the $e_{n+1}$-axis (i.e. integrate over ${\rm SO}(n)$ with normalized Haar measure).

Could you maybe also comment on how I would show the next two steps in the edit?

(1) Contrapositive. (2) Show $V=\Bbb H_m(\Bbb R^{n+1})$ has $Z(V)=1$ (and is a rep).
